# Run a powershell script or batch file on target server after publish

Tags: visual-studio, iis, tfsbuild, publishing, webdeploy

I'm using visualstudio.com and Hosted build controller to build and publish my website to a server with web deploy. 
After the publish I want to execute a file (powershell script or batch file).

I know that I could create a Windows Service that runs on target server and uses the `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor changes and run a file when it detects a file change.

But is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've **customized your XAML workflow** to add a new Activity (of type *InvokeProcess* maybe?) to handle the *Publish* part.

If so, you can **add another Activity** that will **execute your custom powershell** (say *custom.ps1*) script like so:

1. Add *custom.ps1* to your source control
2. Add the **folder** of *custom.ps1* to those used when building (Right click your build definition > Edit Build Definition... > Source Settings tab > add your folder here)
3. Add a new *InvokeProcess* Activity after the publish, that will call **powershell.exe** and give "*custom.ps1*" as the argument.

The basic idea is: deploy the .ps1 along-side your source code, and execute it after publishing is over.

Also, I strongly encourage you to take a look at Ewald Hofman's great series, especially the following:
http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/part-14-execute-a-powershell-script.aspx